# Vector of objects in Matlab without knowing dimension

Tags: matlab

I have this code:

```
allObjects=[]
for i=1:100
   allObjects(end+1) = MyObject();   % push the object to the end of my vector
end
```

But this prints:

> Conversion to double from MyObject is not possible.

Same thing if i declare allObjects as a cell array

```
 allObjects = {}
```

How can I have a vector of objects in Matlab, consider I can't know how many objects I will need to store?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`allObjects = MyObject.empty` will give you an empty array of objects of class `MyObject`. `empty` is a Public Static method of all non-abstract classes designed for this purpose. Type `doc empty` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to do

```
allObjects=[MyObject]
```

This will tell matlab that allObjects is a vector of MyObject

The only problem is that the real objects will start from index 2 (because you push an element with `end+1`)